# Forced assigning parfor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

Is it possible to force the parfor iteration numbers in MATLAB? For example, if the loop is i=1:1000, then is it possible to assign it in the following manner:

> i=1:250 ---> core 1
>
> i=251:500 ---> core 2
>
> i=501:750 ---> core 3
>
> i=751:1000 ---> core 4

Comment: I don't think so, but more importantly: why would you want to do this? MATLAB's pretty good at distributing computational effort. I wouldn't be surprised if it used an asymmetric distribution in cases where the iterations vary with respect to computational effort (though I've never checked the docs to find out if this was indeed the case)

Comment: You can't assign to specific cores, but if you want the cores to process 4 chunks of your problem, you could do `parfor j=1:4;for i=(1+250*(j-1)):(250*j);...` which ought to work, but as Andras says, I can't think why this would be a good idea.

Comment: This may seem naive, but is vital: is it guaranteed that with j=1:4, all the four different j-computations will go to 4 different cores?

Comment: Sorry, just to rephrase: how to assure that all the four j-iterations go to 4 different cores - and better still, to know which core has got which j-value computation (e.g. core 3 has j=1; core 1 has j=2 etc). This is assuming that at this point parfor cannot be forced into j=1-->core1, j==2-->core2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with `parfor`, but you can do something basically equivalent with either with `spmd` or `parfeval`.

In [`parfeval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html):

```
for fidx = 1:4
    range = (((fidx - 1)*250)+1):(fidx*250)
    f(fidx) = parfeval(@bodyFcn, 1, range);
end
```

In `spmd`:

```
spmd
    for i = drange(1, 1000)
        ...
    end
end
```

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/using-a-for-loop-over-a-distributed-range-for-drange.html for documentation about `drange`.

Comment: Tried both. But cannot force assign 4 blocks of codes to four individual cores.

Comment: I don't understand - the code above divides up the work into 4 so that different workers operate on the body. (Well, I suppose the `parfeval` version doesn't *guarantee* that different workers operate on different evaluations, but the `spmd` version does). What happens when you try?